# Ionic 2 - How can I queue async promises made to storage

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, ionic2, task-queue, ionic-storage

I am developing an app with Ionic 2. I am using the Ionic Native Storage plugin to store key-value pairs. In hopes to help concurrency issues, I want to queue the calls that are made to the storage.

For example, I have saveJob(), getJob() and deleteJob() which all return Promises.

Let's say these methods were called at random.

```
this.storageService.saveJob().then((result) => {
 // blah blah
})

this.storageService.saveJob().then((result) => {
 // blah blah
}) 

this.storageService.deleteJob().then((result) => {
 // blah blah
}) 

this.storageService.getJob().then((result) => {
 // blah blah
})  

this.storageService.saveJob().then((result) => {
 // blah blah
})
```

Is it possible for me to queue these calls? I would like to handle this in the StorageService provider so that the rest of my app can continue calling the StorageService without even noticing the calls are queued.

Comment: With async/await? Of course, the rest of the app should be aware that it uses promises and use async/await as well.

Answer (score 0):

As all the methods are returning promises, you can call the other method in the success or failure callback.
For example if A(),B() and C() are three methods to be called, you will call A() and B and C will be called as and when you receive response in A() callback or B() callback respectively.